# How to get figure name without displaying the figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In Matlab I can get the figure name by using:

```
get(figure(1), 'Name')
```

where I now get the first figures name. However with this method the figure pops up and becomes visible, even though I have set `set(0,'DefaultFigureVisible','off')`.

How can I get the figure name without showing the figure on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the figure handle itself instead of invoking `figure`:

```
get(1, 'Name')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know the handler:

```
get(get(0,'Children'),'Name')
```